# Autocomplete with rendering scripts not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In MVC project, For create form, I need to perform 2 operations

1.validate the required field -In view I included the following lines for this

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

2.for one field I should give Autocomplete - For this I included AJAX script in the same View.Scripts is as

```
 <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#searchString").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Home/searchUser",
                            type: "POST",
                            datatype: "json",
                            data: { searchString: request.term },
                            success: function (data) {

                                response($.map(data, function (item) {

                                    return { value: item.LoginName };

                                }))
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>      
    </head>
```

But When I included both(Validation and Autocompletion),Autocomplete is not working.

When I commented the following lines,Autocomplete is working,validation is not working

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

When the above lines are not commented,validation is working,Autocompletion of field is not working.

Comment: Are you using `Jquery UI` for autocomplete ? Did you check browser console to see any console errors ? Also it will be better to show some  of your `_Layout.cshtml` code.

Comment: Please refer the edited part,I included Javascript for autocomplete

Comment: And I cant able to read the autocomplete field value in controller using " Request.Form["FieldName"] "

Comment: What validation? On what property? You have not shown any of the code necessary to understand your issue

Comment: You are using Jsonresult or web api to get data show code of controller or apicpontroller and along with model.

Comment: First learn validation from [here](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/enable-client-side-valiation-in-mvc) and Auto Complete from [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-jQuery-AutoComplete-TextBox-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) ,Then integrate both together then tell if you have issues.

Comment: @stom,Yes,thank you.I read both link you provided.Now I can able to fetch the value from form in controller using " Request.Form["FieldName"] ",And I included the validation stuffs also..But if validation works,Autocomplete is not working..

Comment: And why are you loading 2 copies of jquery? (one wipes out the other). And you almost certainly have you scripts in the wrong order)

Comment: You mean this " <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>                                                                                                          <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> " in head section

Comment: Thank you@stom, issue is becuase of the jquery copies..Now it is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue may be that you are not using the `script` files in correct order.

Try the below steps patiently.

First install all the required `dependencies` from `Nuget`

**1.** [jQuery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery/)

**2.** [jQuery.UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.UI.Combined/)

**3.** [Bootstrap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap)

**4.** [Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/)

**5.** [Jquery.Validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.validation)

**6.** [jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive/)

In your `_Layout.cshtml` view all the script files should be in above order as mentioned below.

**Create your View Model**

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Enter search text")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

}
```

**Add Action Methods**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

   return View();
}



[HttpPost]
public JsonResult searchUser(string prefix)
{
   string searchTerm = prefix.ToLower();

   var dummyUsers = new[] 
     {   new { UserId = 1, UserName = "John" },
         new { UserId = 1, UserName = "Foo" },
         new { UserId = 2, UserName = "Foo2" },
         new { UserId = 3, UserName = "Bar" },
         new { UserId = 3, UserName = "Bar2" }
     }.ToList();

        // just used dummy users for demo , instead use your real database repository

    var users =  (from user in dummyUsers
                 where user.UserName.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1
                  select new
                  {
                     label = user.UserName,
                     val = user.UserId
                  }).ToList();

        return Json(users);
   }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
    public ActionResult AddUser(UserViewModel user)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

**Add Views:**

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>  

    @RenderBody()

    @*Always add scripts before closing the html body tag*@

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#txtUser").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/searchUser/',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return item;
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("#hfUser").val(i.item.val);
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Index.chtml**

```
@model     FooDemoMvc.Models.UserViewModel

@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post,new { @class= "form-horizontal" }))
    {

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Search User:</label>
            <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { id = "txtUser", @class = "form-control" })

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId, new { id = "hfUser" })

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10">

                    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
                </div>
            </div>



    }
```

**Note:**

In this example I have added `Script` and `Css` files directly in `_Layout.cshtml` , but you can actually bundle them to increase the performance of your app, check [this](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/aspnet-mvc-4-performance-optimization-with-bundling-and-minification).

Comment: Thank you stom for your explanation in patience manner. It helped me.

Comment: @Kiruthik Glad to know :) If it helped you then you can either `UpVote` or even accept the answer by clicking the tick mark on left side of this answer.

Comment: I cant upvote as my reputaion is low, i accepted the answer..keep doing good work.Thanks again

Comment: @Kiruthik , Oh Ok :) , My advice would be if of you are new to `mvc` ,`Jquery` etc check [this](http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/) and learn , All the best.